# Video does not play correctly in webview plugin

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm having trouble playing video (iframe) through webview_flutter

The videos are hosted on various platforms, Vimeo, Youtube, Facebook, Instagram. And what is causing me more problems is Vimeo, I believe because of the ad that appears before the original video.
When you do not have an ad the video loads, but when you have to run an ad before, the app screen will blink and play nothing.

Ps; I can not disable the ads.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was some problem in the android emulator, I tested on physical devices and ran without problem.